# Tensorflow : TypeError: 'TensorShape' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow

I have one simple placeholder :

```
input_x = tf.placeholder(name='tensor_a',shape=[2,3,4],dtype=tf.int32)
```

I want to take shape index and use it inside variable as argument something like:

```
var_b = tf.get_variable('name_a',shape=[input_x.get_shape()[0],2],dtype=tf.float32,initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer())
```

and

```
var_c = tf.get_variable('name_b',shape=[input_x.get_shape()[1],2],dtype=tf.float32,initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer())
```

Complete program:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

tf.reset_default_graph()

input_x = tf.placeholder(name='tensor_a',shape=[2,3,4],dtype=tf.int32)

var_b = tf.get_variable('name_a',shape=[input_x.get_shape()[0],2],dtype=tf.float32,initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer())
var_c = tf.get_variable('name_b',shape=[input_x.get_shape()[1],2],dtype=tf.float32,initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer())

sum_c=tf.add(var_b,var_c)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(sum_c,feed_dict={input_x:np.random.randint(0,10,[2,3,4])}))
```

But i am getting this error:

```
TypeError: 'TensorShape' object is not callable
```

How i can achieve that thing?

Edit : I am getting another error if i am trying to reshape that :

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

tf.reset_default_graph()

input_x = tf.placeholder(name='tensor_a',shape=[None,None],dtype=tf.int32)
print(input_x.get_shape())

var_b = tf.get_variable('name_a',shape=[4,4],dtype=tf.float32,initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer())
var_c = tf.get_variable('name_b',shape=[4,4],dtype=tf.float32,initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer())
vac_d= tf.get_variable('name_d',shape=[var_c.shape[0],60],dtype=tf.float32,initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer())
reshape_ = tf.reshape(var_c,[input_x.shape[0],input_x.shape[1],-1])
print(reshape_)
sum_c=tf.add(var_b,var_c)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(sum_c,feed_dict={input_x:np.random.randint(0,10,[2,2])}))
```

error:

```
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'list'> to Tensor. Contents: [Dimension(None), Dimension(None), -1]. Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

Comment: In `numpy`, and probaby `tensorflow`, `shape` is an attribute, not a method.  So putting `()` after it produces this error: `input_x.shape()`

Answer (score 0):

change

```
var_b = tf.get_variable('name_a',shape=[input_x.shape()[0],2],dtype=tf.float32,initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer())
var_c = tf.get_variable('name_b',shape=[input_x.shape()[1],2],dtype=tf.float32,initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer())
```

to

```
var_b = tf.get_variable('name_a',shape=[input_x.shape[0],2],dtype=tf.float32,initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer())
var_c = tf.get_variable('name_b',shape=[input_x.shape[1],2],dtype=tf.float32,initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer())
```

Comment: I am getting error if there is input placeholder is [None,None] , is there any method i can solve this , see the edit in question ?

Comment: Use `tf.shape(input_x)[0]` instead of `input_x.shape()[0]`